# Pro's of using Docker Virtual Networks

Tags: docker

What are the pros of having Docker containers running and communicating with each other through a Docker virtual network instead of simply having them communicate with each other through the host machine? Say I have container A exposed through port 8000 on the host machine (-p 8000:8000) and container B exposed through port 9000 on the host machine (-p 9000:9000). Container A can communicate with container B through `host.docker.internal:9000` but, if they were deployed in the same Docker network, A would be able to communicate with B simply through `<name of container B>:9000`. The latter is obviously neater in my opinion, but other than that what are its benefits?

Answer (score 2):

**Security** . 
By creating a private network that is only accessible to internal Docker services, you remove a door for attacks to occur. A common architecture is

```
-pub---> PROXY --priv---> MAIN SERVICE --priv--> DATABASE
```

Only the *proxy* needs to be exposed to the public (host) network interface. All 3 services can be part of a private network where internal traffic occurs.

**Simplification** . 
The private network traffic is considered "trusted" so no need for SSL cert (HTTPS) and having every service implement SSL/TLS verification.
It is also typically (or should always be) much faster than the public facing networking which means no need for some optimisation used on the web (zipping or other compression schemes, caching).

**Multi VMs**
When services span multiple VMs, they are typically not tied to a specific VM. This allows components (Containers, Tasks, etc) to even be moved around to different or new VMs by orchestrators (Kubernetes, Mesos,...). The communication between services is done through a private (overlay) network spanning all the VMs. Your service then only needs to refer to other services by name and let the orchestrator reroute it correctly.